# How to implement Audio Recorder in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to implement Audio Recorder functionality in Flutter which is the same as WhatsApp Audio recording functionality with animation. I've searched lots of sites, documentation, and plugins but couldn't find anything perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with this plugin for recording audio. https://github.com/ZaraclaJ/audio_recorder/

You could use platform-specific code to link your UI with android's audio recording API. The plugin listed above uses a similar approach and you can get an idea of how to implement this by following the code on the Github repository.

Comment: Sorry, but this not as expected which I have wanted. I wanted a similar kind of functionality in Flutter which is the same as WhatsApp audio recording animation.